# grails spring social twitter plugin

Tags: grails, twitter, spring-social

I'm using spring social in my app to handle the integration with twitter. If I'm logged in my app, everything works fine, but if I'm not logged in, every time I try to do anything with twitter I get a "Authorization revoked" exception.